# Is it possible to give a top-level function access to an object's members in C++?

Tags: c++, c, class, object, encapsulation

So I'm writing some wrapper classes for GUI programming in Win32. I'm starting with a `Window` class, and so far it contains a `MainLoop` method that is basically a clone of the standard Win32 `WinMain` function. That way, one can do something like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR szCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  Window *win = new Window();

  // Do all your widget creation and add it to the window object...

  return win->MainLoop(hInst, hPrev, szCmdLine, nCmdShow);
}
```

Inside the window object's `MainLoop` method, it must create the new Win32 window by setting its `lpfnWndProc` member. This member, as any Win32 programmer knows, is a function pointer to a specifically defined `WndProc` function. The problem is, if I were to create a `WndProc` function, I would need access to that window object's members (so that it knew what to draw on the window, etc.). This leaves me two options (that I know of):

1. I can define `WndProc` at the top level, but that cuts off access to the object's members.
2. I can define it as a class method, but then it's not the exact function type that `lpfnWndProc` asks for, so I can't set it!

Can anyone help me unravel this catch-22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create window map and when you create new window just add it to this global map. You can use simple linked list instead of course.

```
map<HWND, Window *> wndmap;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    Window *pWnd = wndmap [hwnd];

    ....
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could also make it a static member function. :)
Anyways, a solution depends on if you need only one window or if you need multiple windows.
First a solution for single windows:

```
// in .h
class Window{
public:
  static LRESULT WINAPI MessageProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
  LRESULT InternalMessageProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
  // ...
};

// in .cpp
#include "Window.h"

Window* global_window = 0;

Window::Window(/*...*/){
  if(!global_window)
    global_window = this;
  else
    // error or exception... or something else
}

LRESULT WINAPI Window::MessageProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  return global_window->InternalMessageProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Now if you want to allow multiple windows, use a `std::map` (or if your compiler supports `std::unordered_map`).
**Edit**: This solution comes with some subtle problems. As @Ben Voigt points out in his comment, you get a chicken and egg problem as the `MessageProc` is called inside of `CreateWindow(Ex)`, but only after the `CreateWindow(Ex)` call you have the window handle. Here's a solution based on Ben's next comment (thanks!):

```
// Window.h stays the same

// in .cpp
#include "Window.h"
#include <map>

std::map<HWND, Window*> window_map;
Window* currently_created_window = 0;

Window::Window(){
  currently_created_window = this;
  window_handle = CreateWindow(/*...*/);
}

LRESULT WINAPI Window::MessageProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  // if the key 'hWnd' doesn't exist yet in the map
  // a new key-value pair gets created and the value gets value-initialized
  // which, in case of a pointer, is 0
  if(window_map[hWnd] == 0){
    // window doesn't exist yet in the map, add it
    window_map[hWnd] = currently_created_window;
  }
  window_map[hWnd]->InternalMessageProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Be cautious though, as the above example isn't thread-safe. You need to mutex-lock the creation of the window:

```
Window::Window(/*...*/){
  Lock lock_it(your_mutex);
  currently_created_window = this;
  window_handle = CreateWindow(/*...*/);
  lock_it.release();
  // rest of the initialization
}
```

The above should do for the thread-safety (I hope).

Comment: The map idea should be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: You've got a chicken and egg problem.  There is no `HWND` until `CreateWindow` calls `WndProc` for the first time, at which point you haven't yet created the object or made an entry in the map.  Missing map entry and no test for lookup failure => crash.

Comment: @Ben: Urgh, ok, didn't know that `CreateWindow(ex)` already calls the registered `WndProc` function... thanks for letting me know. Any ideas how to work-around this? I'm currently thinking of one myself...

Comment: Use `window_map.find(hWnd)` instead, and handle the case where it's not found.  If there's no polymorphism, the `Window` object can be created just-in-time, but usually you have to be flexible enough to allow subclasses.  Also, there's a opaque pointer passed into `CreateWindow` and retrievable from `WndProc(..., WM_CREATE, ...)`, but `WM_CREATE` is not the first message processed by the new window.

Answer (score 1):

`WndProc` cannot be an instance member function, because Windows will not pass any hidden `this` parameter.  It can be namespace scope or a static member.

One simple solution is to use a `map<HWND, Window*>` to find the object, and then forward parameters to a method on the object.

Note that `WndProc` can maintain the map itself, since `CreateWindow` provides an opaque user parameter that shows up in `WM_CREATE` which is useful for carrying the `Window *`, and then you remove the entry in `WM_DESTROY`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Define your WndProc as a static class member - this will then be compatible (for all compilers I'm aware of) with non-member function pointer, such as those used in Win32 programming.

But I have to say that this is a bit of a waste of time - there are a zillion Windows class libraries out there, and I don't think the world really needs another one.

Comment: The standard requires that taking the address of a static member returns an ordinary function pointer, same as taking the address of a global function.

Comment: @Ben Sigh. I've been critiqued here and on comp.lang.c++ for suggesting this before, by some pretty weighty people too. And now I'm getting critiqued for putting in caveats. You can't win!

Comment: AFAIK, the only way a static member function might be incompatible with a global function is if you've not specified the language linkage and the default language linkage/calling convention were different.  But the compiler is supposed to catch that (no implicit conversion between pointer-to-function of different language linkages) and it's easy enough to fix by specifying the language linkage/calling convention explicitly.  Perhaps others knew of major compilers which didn't comply with the standard-mandated behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds you need to declare the function without defining it. That's what prototypes are for.

```
class Object;

void f(Object* o);

class Object {
    public:
        ...
        void some_method() {
           ... &f ...
        }

        void another_method() {
           ...
        }

        ...
};

void f(Object* o) {
    ...
    o->another_method();
    ...
}
```

The other way around might also be possible.

```
class Object {
    public:
        ...
        void some_method();
        void another_method();
        ...
};

void f(Object* o) {
    ...
    o->another_method();
    ...
}

void Object::some_method() {
    ... &f ...
}

void Object::another_method() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem there is that `lpfnWndProc` must point to a function declared as `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)`, which means I'm unable to pass in an object to the function.

Comment: @ikegami: Next time try reading the whole question, not just the title.

Comment: @Dutch, LPARAM is a pointer. There's no problem passing an object to it.

Comment: @ikegami: `lParam` already has a well-defined message-dependent meaning, set by the OS window manager which actually calls `WndProc`.  It's not available to hold a `this` pointer.

Comment: @Ben Voight, That's not true. The message is only defined by the OS for some messages. If the message in question is one of those messages, then @Dutch can't pass an object to the function.

Comment: @ikegami: If the parameter isn't under his control for ANY invocation, then he can't rely on it to pass a pointer to his `Window` object.